# Filtering NSArray of NSDictionaries from values in another NSArray while preserving order

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsarray

I've got two arrays.

The first array is simply a list of country names, in a very specific order.

```
countryNames = ["Canada", "USA", "Mexico"];
```

The second array is a collection of country objects.

```
countries = [ {name: "USA", foo: "bar"}, {name: "Italy", foo: "bar"}, {name: "Canada", foo: "bar"}, {name: "Mexico", foo: "bar"} ]
```

I need to filter `countries` using the `countryNames` array, while preserving the order of `countryNames`.

My first attempt filtered correctly, but doesn't preserve the order:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name in %@", countryNames];
NSArray *filteredCountries = [countries filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

I think what's happening is the order of countries is being preserved, minus the ones not found in `countryNames`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying to avoid this, but so far this is the only way I know how:

```
NSMutableArray *filteredCountries = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];
NSArray *countryNames = ... // list of country names. this order matters
NSArray *countries = ...    // array of country objects
for (NSString *name in countryNames) {
    for (NSDictionary *dict in countries) {
        if ([[dict objectForKey:@"name"] isEqualToString:name]) {
            [filteredCountries addObject:dict];
        }
    }
}
```

It sucks, but it ships. Still welcoming a better, more elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

countries should stay in the order that items were found in.  The simplest thing to do would be to reorder countries to the proper order then filter them or simply sort them after your predicate filters them.  You could also add an order field to countries and then use sortedArrayUsingSelector:

See the docs here: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Collections/Articles/Arrays.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000132-SW5

Comment: Both of these objects are coming back from a webservice request, and the client will have no way of knowing how to sort `countries`. The server is sorting `countryNames` by `created_at`, so that must be responsible for determining order.

Comment: Okay, so maybe I don't understand the issue exactly.  Is countries in the correct order but countryNames is not?  SHould they be in this order "USA", "Italy", "Canada"  or "Canada", "USA", "Mexico"?  In other words what is the result that you would like back from the Predicate?

Comment: I only care about the order of `countryNames`. The result from the predicate should be [{Canada}, {USA}, {Mexico}].

Comment: I know why you were confused. My predicate example in my question was wrong. I just edited it, so my intent should be clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Dictionaries are unordered collections. There is no order in it. You should maintain keys in an array which would maintain order and then sort out using the array objects. Have a look at [this link](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/103122-prevent-nsmutabledictionary-being-sorted.html) for reference.

Thanks.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm doing. `countryNames` is my array of keys, in a particular order. Using those keys, I need to grab the particular dictionary from `countries` whose name matches the key from `countryNames`.